# Not able to assign styles where image created dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this code for creating image dynamically but style not getting assign

```
var descriptionicon = $("<img />")
    .prop("id", i)
    .prop("src", "images/Actions-mail-mark-task-icon.png")
    .css({
        width: '30px;',
        height: '30px;'
    });
```

Comment: the css not getting assigned or the attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ";" from the CSS syntax. Updte your code like below.

```
 var descriptionicon = $("<img />")
.prop("id", i)
.prop("src", "images/Actions-mail-mark-task-icon.png")
.css({
    width: '30px',
    height: '30px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the semicolons out of the attribute values:

```
var descriptionicon = $("<img />")
    .prop("id", i)
    .prop("src", "images/Actions-mail-mark-task-icon.png")
    .css({
        width: '30px',
        height: '30px'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code

```
var descriptionicon = $("<img />")
    .prop("id", i)
    .prop("src", "images/Actions-mail-mark-task-icon.png")
   .css({
   'font-size' : '10px',
   width : '30px',
   height : '10px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid unwanted semicolon(;) from the CSS method.

```
var descriptionicon = $("<img />")
.prop("id", i)
.prop("src", "images/Actions-mail-mark-task-icon.png")
.css({
    width: '30px',
    height: '30px'
});
```